# ReferenceError: mapkit is not defined when referred from an internal page

Tags: mapkit, svelte, sveltekit

I am using mapkit, which is displayed on `/map`. If I load `/map` directly, mapkit loads the map as intended. However, if I load any other page on my site and then access `/map`, I get the following error: `ReferenceError: mapkit is not defined`.

I tried playing around with `onMount`, `afterMount`, and reactive statements, but nothing seems to work. For context, I have every page set to pretender.

Here is my `map.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(() => {
        mapkit.init({
            authorizationCallback: function (done) {
                fetch('/api/gettoken')
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then(done);
            }
        });
        let map = new mapkit.Map('map');
    });
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<div id="map" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load order is not guaranteed to be correct like this. You could use a dynamic import instead:

```js
onMount(async () => {
    await import('https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js');

    // mapkit should be defined from here
});
```